# Underwater ROV Variable Ballast

Tags: underwater

How would you guys recommend making a variable ballast system for an underwater robot? I was thinking about this problem earlier and I was trying to figure out if there was a way to make one that didn't require a tank of compressed air.

Answer (score 2):

Variable ballast on ROVs in practice is usually limited to just the really big ones, for several reasons:

1. In general, you only need to vary your ballast when you're trying to get an exact amount of buoyancy at great depth -- when that amount would be different than at the surface (due to compression of various components)
2. The pressure housing required adds a lot of size and weight
3. The power required for the pump or compressor is significant
4. It requires more maintenance

That's not to say it can't be done on a small scale, for slight adjustments to ballast.  [Underwater gliders use variable ballast as "buoyancy engines"](http://my.fit.edu/~swood/GliderThesisFinal.pdf).

Depending on your specific application, you might get away with one of the following alternatives:

1. Descending with a dropweight, then shedding it at the desired depth (repeat for rapid ascent)
2. Having a canister of lead shot, and dropping the balls in a controlled fashion until you have reached the desired buoyancy -- useful if you are going to collect samples
3. Use more powerful motors and actively compensate for buoyancy